# Extending PHP based MySQL query with additional session variable?

Tags: php

I have a single session variable of AgreeNum that dynamically inserts into my PHP based MySQL query.  I am trying to add a second session variable called AgreeNum and cannot figure out the correct syntax to add the second variable?  Here is the snippet, everytime I try to add AND after the WHERE clause it blows up:

```
$ParamAgreeNum_WADAsarenewals = "-1";
if (isset($_GET['AgreeNum'])) {
  $ParamAgreeNum_WADAsarenewals = (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) ? $_GET['AgreeNum'] : addslashes($_GET['AgreeNum']);
}
$ParamEmail_WADAsarenewals = "-1";
if (isset($_GET['Email'])) {
  $ParamEmail_WADAsarenewals = (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) ? $_GET['Email'] : addslashes($_GET['Email']);
}
mysql_select_db($database_home, $home);
$query_WADAsarenewals = sprintf("SELECT AgreeNum, sName, Address1, CityStZip, Email, EffectiveDate, Year1, Year2, Year3, Year4, YearPick, authid, ccinfo FROM sarenewals WHERE AgreeNum = %s", GetSQLValueString($ParamAgreeNum_WADAsarenewals, "text"));
```

I tried to update with this on the sprintf and it does not work:

```
$query_WADAsarenewals = sprintf("SELECT AgreeNum, sName, Address1, CityStZip, Email, EffectiveDate, Year1, Year2, Year3, Year4, YearPick, authid, ccinfo FROM sarenewals WHERE AgreeNum = %s", GetSQLValueString($ParamAgreeNum_WADAsarenewals, "text") " AND Email = %s", GetSQLValueString($ParamEmail_WADAsarenewals, "text"));
```

Comment: Not sure I follow your approach, but you definitely have a typo. if(isset($_GET['AgreeNum'])){ is followed by $_GET['Email'] get/set value. I suspect your real issue is with sprintf() and not MySQL.

Comment: yes, you are correct...that was a typo.  how do i append this second Param to the sprintf statement correctly?

Updated the code with sprintf and it still does not work, any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to write the full string, before passing through the variables that are used as arguments:

```
sprintf("SELECT AgreeNum, sName, Address1, CityStZip, Email, EffectiveDate,
Year1, Year2, Year3, Year4, YearPick, authid, ccinfo 
FROM sarenewals 
WHERE AgreeNum = %s AND Email = %s",
GetSQLValueString($ParamAgreeNum_WADAsarenewals, "text"),
GetSQLValueString($ParamEmail_WADAsarenewals, "text"));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$query_WADAsarenewals = sprintf(
    "SELECT AgreeNum, sName, Address1, CityStZip, Email, EffectiveDate, Year1, Year2, Year3, Year4, YearPick, authid, ccinfo 
     FROM sarenewals 
     WHERE AgreeNum = %s AND Email = %s", 
    GetSQLValueString($ParamAgreeNum_WADAsarenewals, "text"), 
    GetSQLValueString($ParamEmail_WADAsarenewals, "text")
);
```